# ContourPlot3D doesn't show all of the curve

Tags: plotting

I am studying a polynomial

`F[x_, y_, z_] := 2*(x^2 - 2 x*y + y^2 - y*z)^2 - y^4 - z^4`.

I tried plotting this:
`a = ContourPlot3D[F[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`

[image]

But I figured out that the line $ \lambda (1, 1, 1) $ also lies on my surface, because $ F[\lambda,\lambda,\lambda] = 0 $.
However, if I plot that together, it doesn't look like that.

`Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line[{{-2, -2, -2}, {2, 2, 2}}]}], a]`

[image]

Comment: As I understand it, `ContourPlot3D` does not show sets of dimension less than two e.g. `ContourPlot3D[(x - y)^2 + (y - z)^2 == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,    2}, {z, -2, 2}]`.

Comment: Thank you! So do you know maybe a way to show also the sets of dimension less than two?

Comment: No, I don't know such a way, expect suggested by you.

Comment: Try   `RegionPlot3D[-.02 <= F[x, y, z] <= .02, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4 ]` which gives roughly what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround using `RegionPlot3D`

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := 2*(x^2 - 2 x*y + y^2 - y*z)^2 - y^4 - z^4
grad = Grad[F[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

RegionPlot3D[-.02 Sqrt[grad . grad ] <=F[x, y, z] <= .02 Sqrt[grad . grad ]
, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,2}, {z, -2, 2} , PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]